# Ubuntur 12.04 - Background Wallpaper shows portrait photo in landscape orientation

Tags: desktop-background, photo, orientation

I want to have some portrait-oriented (longer vertical than horizontal dimensions) jpg files for my wallpaper, but they keep being displayed in landscape-orientation (rotated anti-clockwise 90deg).  The original photos show in correct orientation in Image Viewer.  Any answers or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That seems a little odd, are you able to open up Image Viewer and rotate it how you want? First I have ever heard of this, it may be the image is too large height wise so you may need to reduce it using a program such a GIMP

Comment: Yes.  Image Viewer allows to me rotate them, and I then save them in the correct orientation.  When I view them from either Image Viewer or Shotwell, they are all in the correct orientation.  When I select them from Background they show correct in the file listing, but then appear rotated to landscape when actually be used for background.  The photos were taken with my iPhone5 and are standard format, so I doubt the vertical to is too high....

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a bug in the wallpaper displayer : it ignores the "Orientation" meta data of the photo. In my case rotating the photo solves the problem because the orientation is rewritten by the program performing the rotation. Still, the Orientation metadata should be taken into account.